# Google App Script: URLFetchApp.fetch with header

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script

I'm trying to fetch data from the rainforestqa API but to gain access I need to send my api_key as a header. The code I already have is as follows,

```
var header = {
     "access-control-allow-headers":"Content-Type",
     "CLIENT_TOKEN" : "API-TOKEN"
}; 

var options = {
     "method" : "post",
     "header" : header
};

UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://app.rainforestqa.com:443/api/1/runs/TESTNUMBER/tests.json?result=failed", options);
```

But this returns 405 error. Does anyone have any ideas why this isn't working?

Thanks

Comment: Since `405` is "`Method not allowed`", I assume the server doesn't allow a POST method on the resource you're trying to access. Have you tried a GET?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. When I change this to `GET` I get a `401` which presumabley means that the header isn't being passed to the server and the authentication isn't working.

Comment: I've just taken a very quick glance at Rainforest and I see `access-control-allow-headers:Content-Type,CLIENT_TOKEN`, which suggests to me that the API key header should be called `CLIENT_TOKEN`. What happens if you change `"api_key"` to `"CLIENT_TOKEN"`?

Comment: Hi thanks again for your help. I've updated my question to show the changes you suggested. However, this still gives a 401. I'm starting to think this might be something to do with rainforestqa's API...

Comment: Note clients should never send `access-control-allow-headers` -- that is for servers to send *to* clients. However, since you're getting a 401 response, that issue not what is causing your problem; it's simply needless code (but it *would* be problem if you tried it in a browser context).

Answer (score 39):

It turns out the answer is as follows, I basically got to this via trial and error.

```
$var options = {
     "async": true,
     "crossDomain": true,
     "method" : "GET",
     "headers" : {
       "CLIENT_TOKEN" : "my-api-key",
       "cache-control": "no-cache"
     }
   };
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://app.rainforestqa.com:443/api/1/runs/test_id/tests.json?result=failed", options);
```

Comment: That's the right way to set the `method` and `headers` but the `crossDomain` and `async` params you included in the options will do nothing.  According to Google's docs those aren't support options: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)  (my guess is they're jQuery options though....adding to the confusion)

Comment: Thank you for this, didn't realize headers needed to be in their own object inside of the options object. Also, the Google documentation is not very helpfull

Answer (score 3):

I believe you have misspelled the word `headers`. 
I know it is an old question, but I did not see this answer before and it might help others who arrive this page.