# How can I pass the Session ID in API Request via Apps Script?

Tags: api, rest, google-apps-script, sessionid, sharpspring

I am trying to access the API of our CRM [Documentation](https://help.sharpspring.com/hc/en-us/sections/115000320047-API) through Google Sheets / Apps Script.
When accessing the API through Postman I have no issues and get the desired results using the following setup:

POST: [https://api.sharpspring.com/pubapi/v1.2/?accountID={{accountID}}&secretKey={{secretKey}}](https://api.sharpspring.com/pubapi/v1.2/?accountID=%7B%7BaccountID%7D%7D&secretKey=%7B%7BsecretKey%7D%7D)

BODY:

```
{
  "id":"12345678912345678999",
  "method": "getOpportunities",
  "params": {
        "where": {},
        "limit":"500",
        "offset": "0"
    }
}
```

Now, when I try to replicate the same in Apps Script I get the following result:

> { result: null,
> error: { code: 102, message: 'Header missing request ID', data: [] },
> id: null }

The function that I am running is as below:

```
function myFunction() {

  var URL = "https://api.sharpspring.com/pubapi/v1.2/?accountID={{accountID}}&secretKey={{secretKey}}"

  var body = {
    "method": "POST",
    "body": raw,
    "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    "redirect": "follow"
  }

  var raw = {
  "method": "getOpportunities",
  "id": "12345678912345678999",
        "params": {
        "where": {},
        "limit":"500",
        "offset": "0"
      }
    }

  var results =  UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL, body).getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(results);
  console.log(data);

}
```

In both I am passing a random session ID "12345678912345678999". I tried finding a session ID in the cookie but that didn't work and I assume that I am on the wrong path there. Passing the id in the header directly didn't work either.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Possible related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35133610/google-app-script-urlfetchapp-fetch-with-header

Comment: The order of the code matters.  Move the object literal for `raw` above `body`.

Comment: tried both, thanks. Unfortunately didn't make a difference. Both in different order and moving the id and other options directly into the header didn't work. Still the same error.